# How do I accept POST requests from Go and write output to a file?

Tags: curl, logging, go

First of all, I'm trying to create a logging service in Go, where it is a lightweight server accepting POST requests with log data from my service.  I'm writing this service in Go because it is supposed to be fast and handle a lot of POST requests at once.  Is my logic sound there?

Anyways, this is my issue.  I'm sending POST requests like this to test:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hello":"world"}' http://localhost:8080/log`

And here is my Go script so far:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "net/http"
)

func logger(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   r.ParseForm()
   fmt.Println(r.Form)
   fmt.Println(r.FormValue("hello"))
}

func main() {
   http.HandleFunc("/log", logger)
   log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

It is outputting:
`map []`

Why is that?  How could I write the POST data to a file on the server?

Thank you very much!
W

Answer (score 1):

`r.Method` contains type of received request (GET, POST, HEAD, PUT, etc.).

You can read data from `r.Body` with `ioutil` and write that data into the file with the same package.

This is for handling only **POST** method, reading data and writing into file (output.txt).

```
if r.Method == "POST" {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error during reading body: %v", err)
    }

    if err := ioutil.WriteFile("output.txt", body, 0644); err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error during writing data: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: `ioutil.WriteFile` is probably not the best solution here since it will truncate the file before writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not POST'ing a form, you're sending json data in the request body.

Read the data directly:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("ERROR:", err)
}
```